# Riley Riddle #9: Get That Party Started

Tags: riddle

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.
My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.
My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.
You might say I'm a polite way to say something quite nasty.

Hint 1:

> The infix is also in the title of some restaurants. The prefix is scientific. The full word *can* be used in place of something sexual, but it has a much more common usage

Hint 2:

> The sushi restaurant in Scarborough inspired the clue for the infix, though you can find restaurants with the same name in West Hollywood and DeKalb, IL. The prefix is one mere element away from being essential to life.

Comment: "Polite Phrase"- thus we are looking for more than one word?

Comment: Nope, maybe use of the word phrase wasn't a good choice.

Comment: Is the infix a proper noun?

Comment: nope "means the head..." is different then "is the head..."

Comment: I want to test my answer before posting it. Is the infix rot13(cngevnepu)?

Comment: Let's just say I didn't have to look up the cipher and I know it isn't :).

Comment: Is it an English word? Or is knowledge of a foreign language needed?

Comment: Sadly, such questions can never be answered easily.This word has foreign origins. It is found in the Oxford dictionary (the first one I checked). It's not typically used in English conversation, though, and when it is, it's likely only in certain communities and in an entirely different context (when someone English uses this word, they are never purposefully communicating the idea of the head of a clan).

Comment: Are there any further clues regarding the suffix besides the one in the puzzle, @flashstorm?

Comment: There doesn't need to be.

Comment: Fair enough. After a couple hours of beating my head against the same wall, I think I have a feasible answer, @flashstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your word be

> COMING?

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> Based on the hints, this word is [OMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omi), a hereditary title reserved for the head of the most powerful Japanese clans. It's also found in the Omi Sushi restaurants in Scarborough, DeKalb, and West Hollywood.

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> This would be CO, carbon monoxide, where a CO detector prevents people dying from CO poisoning. It's a scientific prefix (chemical formula), where by adding an oxygen, removing an oxygen, or adding hydrogen becomes vital for life.

My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> This refers to the [MING dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty) whose first emperor was the [Hongwu Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hongwu_Emperor). He united China against the Mongols and brought new prosperity to the land in the 14th century.

You might say I'm a polite way to say something quite nasty.

> ***No comment.***

@Pugmonkey has found a nifty connection to the title, thanks very much!!:

> *"I'm comin' up so you better you better get this party started"*, which are song lyrics from "Get the Party Started" by P!nk.

Comment: I debated about this one, but I'd argue that this is the non-polite version of saying... yeah...

Comment: That is fair, although there are definitely politer ways of saying it, there are definitely cruder ways I'd imagine as well...that mixed in with the second hint alternate definition made me think of this. I definitely had that debate as well, @Joe-You-Know!

Comment: This would also fit the title considering the song lyrics rot13(V'z pbzva' hc fb lbh orggre lbh orggre trg guvf cnegl fgnegrq) by rot13(Cvax).  But I agree, this hardly fits the "polite" clue.

Comment: Ding! More references: For the prefix, many/most homes now have carbon monoxide sensors, which are machines designed to alert people if there is too much CO (thereby enforcing a ban on CO in the air). For the suffix, the Ming dynasty only existed because they were able to defeat the Mongols. This was an "exceptional start" as a reference to John Green's Crash Course World History, where a common catchphrase was that the Mongols are the exception.

Given that literally no one has commented on the less polite word, but they are willing to use this word, I say the polite clue was a good one.

Answer (score 2):

*partial thoughts:*

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> -boso- Fijian word for boss.

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> ?

My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> -ming, Ming Dynasty, China. Egypt ones are all too long. Maybe -tang

You might say I'm a polite phrase for something quite nasty.

> scheming, defaming, ransoming, pogroming, blaspheming, flimflamming,

Comment: One of these is right :)

Comment: I would assume the third-

Comment: Or perhaps @flashstorm means one of the words in the fourth spoiler tag/quote is right...? :P

Comment: He edited the words in the fourth spoiler tags after I made the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A hedonist?

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> A don is the boss of the mafia.

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> High-Efficiency machines, or HE, force people to use HE detergents and effectively ban lower efficiency ones.

My suffix is an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> I can't figure this one out.

You might say I'm a polite phrase for something quite nasty.

> YOLO

Comment: I think this is a loose enough fit for most of the clues that you know it's not quite right :P. Thought it did prompt a minor edit to make a clue more clear, so thanks :)

Comment: The only thing I could think of, which is indeed a stretch, is a wordplay :^) 13(vfg > Vfg > "1fg", naq orvat svefg vf nyjnlf tbbq)

Comment: @iiiidk, Man, I was actually really sure of the infix, too.

Comment: I was surprised there was another word that was such a close fit for the clue! I just did a search, though, and I couldn't find a word fitting a *don* wildcard search that conformed to the rest of the clues.

Answer (score 1):

**3rd Attempt** (Close enough to the second attempt to post here)
Are you

> Shaming?

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> The leader of a powerful clan is known as the big Ham! :D

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> Many email providers will use spam/sham filtering. They filter out shams! Also, youtube/facebook/twitter will prevent hate speech, which is shaming.

My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> Ming Dynasty

You might say I'm a polite way to say something quite nasty.

> Yes, shaming is a polite way to say bullying or swearing, or racism.

---

**2nd Attempt** (probably wrong, but I'm optimistic)
Are you

> Spamming?

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> The leader of the tribe of Israel, the Great I AM?

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> Many email providers will use spam filtering.

My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> Ming Dynasty

You might say I'm a polite way to say something quite nasty.

> Yes, spamming is quite nasty indeed. It's better than saying, stop being a talentless loser with no skillz. Get 1337, don't spam fireballs.

Comment: The infix clue confuses me. In any case, is a tribe and a clan comparable? I guess they're pretty close.

This is close to being an "alternate answer" (assuming the infix answer makes sense, but you'll have to explain that to me), but my argument against it is that "spamming" isn't the polite way to say something nasty, it is itself the only way to say "spamming". Like, there's no other way to communicate that idea that is nastier. The intention of the clue is that this word is used in place of a similar word one might not use in polite company.

Comment: @flashstorm. The infix is a reference to Judaism. Their head/leader/deity, is known as rot13(Gur Terng V NZ)

Comment: I see. I wouldn't disrespect the name of a diety by only using part of their name in a clue, I would just clue the word "am" another way. Your thought process is very close though :)

Comment: @flashstorm, as in, the answer is similar, or my clues fit well?

Comment: The philosophy behind your answers fit well. The real answers, though,  fit better than your particular choices.

Comment: @flashstorm, I updated my answer. I think I got it this time!

Comment: I would use the word "bullying", "swearing" and "racism" in polite company. Plus, no actual clan refers to they head that way. Your last answer was closer, unfortunately. What other culture might relate? Also, are you considering the title? That might help to.

Comment: @flashstorm Darn it. I thought I had it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your word

> Dishelmming?

My infix means the head of a powerful clan.

> Helm can be used as a position of leadership.

My prefix has a machine enforcing its ban.

> Dish - dish washers are machines that prevent / ban dishes from being dirty.

My suffix had an exceptional start to a dynasty.

> Ming Dynasty

You might say I'm a polite way to say something quite nasty.

> Though I couldn't find it being used this way, it could be used in reference to someone being beheaded.

For the title "Get That Party Started"

> The Yeah Yeah Yeah's song "Heads Will Roll" talks a lot about dancing

Comment: This is clever! Unfortunately, I wouldn't really consider rot13(orurqqvat gb or anfgl). You're really close though on your interpretation for how the title relates to the word :).

Comment: @flashstorm when you say in your hint rot13(Gur vasvk vf nyfb gur gvgyr bs fbzr erfgnhenagf, qb lbh zrna gung gur jbeq sbe gur vasvk vf gur ragver gvgyr bs fbzr erfgnhenagf be qb lbh zrna gung gur jbeq vf va gur gvgyr bs fbzr erfgnhenagf?)

Comment: rot13(V'ir guvax V'ir bayl frra vg va gur gvgyr bs gur erfgnhenag.)